# How to split this complex string

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have a variable string `mymvariable`

which contains :

```
864827,,,34200,Sète ,,,445958,,,30220,AIGUES MORTES,,,169807,,,34570,PIGNAN,,,546049,,,13006,MARSEILLE,,
```

I would like to cast this string to an array like this:

```
1 864827,,,34200,Sète ,,, 
2 445958,,,30220,AIGUES MORTES,,, 
3 169807,,,34570,PIGNAN,,, 
4 546049,,,13006,MARSEILLE,,
```

I have try to use:

```
var array = myvariable.split(",");
```

But when I do a array[0] that give me the first field here :

> 864827

I would like to have the first line when I do array[0] like this:

> 1 864827,,,34200,Sète ,,,

Is it possible to format the string like this ?

Thanks you

Comment: What is a "first line" here exactly? What's the rule that separates one "line" from another in that endless string?

Comment: Does the string follow a fixed pattern?

Comment: why you have tagged `columnsorting`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution using regexp:

```js
const str = "864827,,,34200,Sète ,,,445958,,,30220,AIGUES MORTES,,,169807,,,34570,PIGNAN,,,546049,,,13006,MARSEILLE,,"
const array = str.split(/(\d+,,,\d+,[a-zA-Zéàêè ]+\s*,,,?)/).filter(Boolean);
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 5):

You could split the array and reduce the array and build subarrays for each 7 items.

```js
var string = '864827,,,34200,Sète ,,,445958,,,30220,AIGUES MORTES,,,169807,,,34570,PIGNAN,,,546049,,,13006,MARSEILLE,,',
    array = string
        .split(',')
        .reduce((r, s, i) => r.concat([i % 7 ? r.pop().concat(s) : [s]]), []);

console.log(array[0]);
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nice and short, but… *squints* …somewhat obfuscated…

Comment: good method, could also add a .map(sa => sa.join(','))  on the end to concat the subarrays  back into comma delimited strings (which is what i think the op is after)